# EPR or NMR sample that will give narrow lines at 4 K

Tags: analytical-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, epr-spectroscopy

We have made a crossed coil setup (X and Y transmit/receiving coils) with a SQUID pick up loop along Z. I have built a similar CW NMR spectrometer with inductive pickup that can detect Teflon NMR with a single scan SNR of around $1$ at around $\pu{6 mT}$ at room temperature. I expect SQUIDs to be more sensitive and the magnetization to stronger by a factor of $\pu{300 K}/\pu{4 K}.$

Now we want to see EPR or NMR lines, probably using it in a CW fashion, i.e. putting a ramp plus lock-in oscillation in X, a CW excitation frequency in Y and demodulating the SQUID signal in Z.

What sample will give us nice, narrow, distinguishable lines at $\pu{4 K}?$

We did try Teflon NMR and copper sulfate EPR and they both failed. I think the reason for the SQUID setup not working (someone who knows about samples told me), is that Teflon $T_2$ gets very short at low temperature, so the lines are very broad.

*Note*: we can only go up to $\pu{10 mT}$ with the X coil. Liquid $\ce{^3He}$ is off our budget.

Comment: Have you thought about endohedral fullerenes, like N@C60?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139245/discussion-on-question-by-gyromagnetic-epr-or-nmr-sample-that-will-give-narrow-l).